# Typescript duplicate definitions creating vscode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building an extension which is using a common library I am also building.  There are 2 projects.

1. Common library
2. Extension

The Extension includes the common library through npm link.

- Common Library imports 'vscode'
- Extension imports 'vscode'

Import statements are:

- In Extension module:

  - `import * as vscode from 'vscode';
    import * as edit from 'vscode-extension-common'`
- In vscode-extension-common:

  - `import * as vscode from 'vscode';`

When building there are duplicate definition errors.
I've attempted to modify tsconfig to exclude duplicates, but doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure if that's possible as the documentation seems to indicate any direct imports from your code are never excluded.

Is there are way to structure this to work without errors?  FYI, I'm fairly new to typescript.

Comment: Need more detail. are you importing vscode as peer dependencies?

Comment: updated description with the import statements